# I want the user to create it's own course in android

Tags: java, android, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-storage

How can I make a user to create new things like a course and add things to it like lessons?

I want the user to create its own course and upload videos to that course.

Comment: I think by writing code!

Comment: Please consult this before asking questions https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask